# Project a point onto a great circle on a hypersphere

Tags: geometry, spherical-geometry

Given two points, $A$ and $B$ that define a [great circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle) on a [unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle) [hypersphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere), how do I find the point $D$ on that great circle that is closest to the point $C$.  (Closest in the sense of having the shortest distance along a great circle)

[image: A diagram showing the points described in the previous paragraph]

I have the points as vectors of numbers in Euclidian space.  If all the points are near each other, I can approximate an answer by projecting C onto a straight line though AB in Euclidean space, then normalising the result to put it on the sphere.  I'm after a more general, more elegant solution.

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1749900) to a similar question makes sense:

> Let  be the target point and  the arc. Consider an arc  through
>  that is perpendicular to . Then the point in  closest to 
> lies in the intersection of  with .

Except I don't know how to find an arc that goes through C and that's perpendicular to the AB arc.

I don't know what the thing I'm trying to do is called, and may be using terms incorrectly - I welcome suggestions for better terminology.

Comment: Same question here. Also wondering: as a slightly-better approximation of your AB straight-line in euclidean space idea, how about instead considering the plane defined by A, B, and the hypersphere origin, and projecting C to the nearest point on it, C' – a straightforward calc in euclidean space. Might that C', scaled to unit length, be the point we're looking for?

Comment: @gojomo, [My answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4859103/72694) may have been so short that you didn't notice it, but it is the only one that actually provides a formula for the nearest point (rather than explaining how to find it using Gram-Schmidt and the like).

Answer (score 2):

Let me answer the question for $S^2\subset {\mathbb R}^3$.

The key example to think about is that the great circle through $A$ and $B$ is the equator. $C$ is a point. What is the closet point $D$ on the equator to $C$? It is the intersection with the meridian through $C$, that is, the great circle through the north pole and $C$, since this one is perpendicular to the equator!

So in general, your great circle through $A$ and $B$ has a unit normal $\vec n$, which also lies on $S^2$ and can be computed by normalizing $OA\times OB$. For the equator example, $\vec n$ is the north or south pole.

The great circle through $\vec n$ and $C$ is what you are looking for. This also says that the distance from $C$ to the great circle $AB$ is the arc-length on this circle, hence the angle between $OC$ and $OD$, but it is also
$$
\frac{\pi}2-\angle (OC, \vec n)=\arcsin |\vec n\cdot \vec x|,
$$
where $\vec x=OC$.

Comment: This is incorrect.  $OA\times OB$ is not a unit vector in general, contrary to your claim.

Comment: @MikhailKatz Right, fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

$\DeclareMathOperator{Lin}{Lin}$
Note that the problem can be reduced to three dimensions, as the great circle and the point in question lie in a three-dimensional subspace (and the shortest paths between them, spherical or not, are contained within that same three-dimensional space).

A great circle is the intersection of a plane through the origin with the sphere. Great circle segments are also (the only) geodesics. It is not hard to see that the shortest spherical path from $C$ to the great circle is along an orthogonal great circle (given by an orthogonal plane).

So all you need to do (generically, there are some degenerate situations mentioned below) is find that orthogonal plane and intersect it with the $AB$-plane (and the unit sphere) and choose one of the points you get.

In practical computational terms, assuming that $A,B,C$ are linearly independent (otherwise, the answer is either $D=C$ or the problem is ill-posed):

1. Find a nonzero vector $v\in \Lin(A,B,C)$ orthogonal to $A,B$ (e.g. via the Gram-Schmidt process).
2. If $v$ is colinear with $C$, then all points in great circle are equidistant to $C$, so you can take e.g. $D=A$.
3. Otherwise, let $w\in \Lin(A,B,C)$ be nonzero orthogonal to $\Lin(C,v)$ (again, Gram-Schmidt works here).
4. Let $D_0\in \Lin(A,B,C)$ be a unit vector orthogonal to $w$ and $v$ (Gram-Schmidt again).
5. Then $D$ is either $D_0$ or $-D_0$ (whichever is closer to $C$, or equivalently, has positive inner product with $C$).

In three dimensions, you can use the cross product instead of Gram-Schmidt, so the result is basically one of the two unit vectors in the direction of $((A\times B)\times C)\times(A\times B)$ if it is nonzero (if it is zero, then $C$ is equidistant to all points in the great circle), namely the one with positive inner product with $C$.

Alternately, you can straight up reduce it to three dimensions by finding unit $B'\in \Lin(A,B)$, $B'\perp A$ (from now on forgetting about $B$ and looking at $B'$ instead), then finding unit $v\perp A,B$ in $\Lin(A,B,C)$. Then express $C$ in the orthogonal basis $A,B',v$ of $\Lin(A,B,C)$. Then follow the above process to obtain the coordinates of $D$ with respect to $A,B',v$, which can then be used to recover $D$ itself.

Answer (score 1):

Let $E=A\times B$.  Let $F=E\times C$.  Let $G$ be the normalisation of $E\times F$.  Then the pair $\{D,-D\}$ is the pair $\{G, -G\}$.  If you want the closest point, choose the one with positive scalar product with $C$.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood the question, the required point $D$ can be found as follows. Let $n$ be a natural number and $S^{n-1}=\{(x_1,\dots,x_{n})\in\mathbb R^n:\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2=1\}$ be the unit hypersphere. Let $A=(x_{A1},\dots,x_{An})$, $B=(x_{B1},\dots,x_{Bn})$ and $C=(x_{C1},\dots,x_{Cn})$. Then $D=\lambda_A A+\lambda_B B$ for some real $\lambda_A$ and $\lambda_B$, which we have to determine.
Since $C\in S^{n-1}$, we have that
$$1=\sum_{i=1}^n (\lambda_Ax_{Ai}+\lambda_Bx_{Bi})^2=\lambda_A^2+ \lambda_A\lambda_B X+\lambda_B^2,$$
where $X=2\sum_{i=1}^n x_{Ai}x_{Bi}$. We have to minimize
$$\sum_{i=1}^n (\lambda_Ax_{Ai}+\lambda_Bx_{Bi}-x_{Ci})^2=2-\lambda_AY-\lambda_BZ,$$
where $Y=2\sum_{i=1}^n x_{Ai}x_{Ci}$ and $Z=2\sum_{i=1}^n x_{Bi}x_{Ci}$.
If $Y=Z=0$ then the vector $C$ is orthogonal to the plane spanned by the vectors $A$ and $B$,
and the distance from $C$ to any point $D$ of the great circle is constant.

Otherwise, swapping the points $A$ and $B$, if needed, we can assume that $Z\ne 0$.
Note that $|X|=2|(A,B)|\le 2$. Moreover, since the points $A$ and $B$ determine the great circle,
$A\ne \pm B$ and so $|X|<2$. Then the set $$\{(\lambda_A,\lambda_B)\in\mathbb R^2:\lambda_A^2+ \lambda_A\lambda_B X+\lambda_B^2=1\}$$ is an ellipse. It follows that if the function $\lambda_AY+\lambda_BZ$ attains a maximum $M$ at this ellipse then it contains a unique point $(\lambda_A,\lambda_B)$ such that $\lambda_AY+\lambda_BZ=M$.
Substituting $m=M/Z$, $y=Y/Z$, we obtain that $\lambda_B=m-\lambda_Ay$, and so the
equation
$$\lambda_A^2+ \lambda_A(m-\lambda_Ay)X+(m-\lambda_Ay)^2-1=0$$
has the discriminant $0=(mX-2my)^2-4(1-Xy+y^2)(m^2-1)$.
That is $m^2(X^2-4Xy+4y^2-4+4Xy-4y^2)+4(1-Xy+y^2)=0$.
It follows $m^2=\frac {4(1-Xy+y^2)}{4-X^2}$, so $m=(\operatorname{sign} Z)\cdot 2\sqrt{\frac {1-Xy+y^2}{4-X^2}}.$
Then $$\lambda_A=\frac{m(2y-X)}{2(1-Xy+y^2)}=(\operatorname{sign} Z)\cdot
\frac{2y-X}{\sqrt{(1-Xy+y^2)(4-X^2)}}$$ and $\lambda_B=m-\lambda_Ay$.